# Simple DOS - how to change Date value to an already defined variable's?

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

At a windows command line, when typing **`Date`** we're asked to type a date value.
But what if we need to change the date to a value which is a memorized (and not type it)?

```
@echo off
set todaysdate=%date%
date 11/11/2012
date %todaysdate%
```

The last line shows this error: `The system cannot accept the date entered.` And then requires us to enter a date.

So what's wrong? Do I need to change the variable's type? Is it possible and how?

---

#### Update:

Problem: Thanks to dbenham, we now know that the problem lies with `Date %todaysdate%` and its alternative `Set "Todaysdate=%DATE:/=-%"` leading to: day of the week + Date.

Example: `Date %todaysdate%` and `Set "Todaysdate=%DATE:/=-%"` (at the 1st script line) will have value: Sat 11/24/2012. So when we ask date (at the last line) to have this value Sat 11/24/2012 it fails since date doesn't accept this value which includes day of the week Sat.

Solutions: I now think of 2 solutions but I'm not sure if they're applicable in cmd.

1st solution is to make a test to see if 1st script line set value includes day of the week (Sat, Sun...) and to trim day of the week.

2nd solution is to change type of 1st line variable, so whichever type the variable has we'll change it to simple date without day of the week (Sun, Mon...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set `todaysdate` take only the last 10 characters (mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy depends on your locale).
this should work:

```
@echo off
set todaysdate=%date:~-10%
date 11/11/2012
date %todaysdate%
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition Ofir. `%date:~4%` does work. Still we didn't solve all the problem as it seems that not on all systems the day of the week is being added. So if we run this `set todaysdate=%date:~4%` on a machine where there's no addition of the day of the week then last line will result in an error.

Comment: Some systems have date format: Sun 11/11/2012 while others 11/11/2012 and others 11/11/12. So we can't just skip a number of characters since length of todaysdate value is different on each system. I think we must do some sort of a test first. Maybe a test to see if **todaysdate** value is accepted on the system? Or Maybe see what exactly is the current **date format of the system** and compare it with **todaysdate** value and then trim chars accordingly.

Comment: I edit my post for a better answer, attacking `%date%` from the end. Hopefully it always ends with the date.

Comment: Yes it works the same as the previous `~4` on my system. Unfortunately I'm not sure if it will work on other systems where command `Date` excludes day of the week and shows for example: `The current date is: 11/29/2012` instead of `Thu 11/29/2012`. So since not sure if `set todaysdate=%date:~-10%` works on all systems, if no one else tests this i'll wait some more time and consider it answered anyway. Thanks again Ofir.

Comment: `set todaysdate=%date:~-10%` takes the last 10 characters of `%date%` so for output of `The current date is: 11/29/2012` it should also work.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but I'm afraid it might not work with this format where it's not 10 characters: 11/29/12. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure but I would hazzard a guess at

```
set todaysdate=%date%
set date=%todaysdate%
```

Comment: no this shows error: `Environment variable date Thu 11/22/2012 not defined` But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a command output redirection:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "Todaysdate=%DATE:/=-%"
<NUL Echo %todaysdate%|DATE 


REM A Test
Set "randomDate=22-22-2012"
Echo %randomDate%
Echo %randomDate%|DATE

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: No didn't work. the pipe only works if `todaysdate` doesn't have `%date%`, while i want to keep this line as it is `set todaysdate=%date%`. thanks anyway.

Comment: i've tested befor answering with todaysdate=%date% and worked, ensure you are testing it in the right way, anyway i've updated my answer now, try it again

Comment: No didn't work either. i'm starting to think we use different versions of Windows but i may be wrong. I test your solutions using batch file on windows 7. On what windows version did you test it? BTW to see it really doesn't work please insert this line between `set` and `Echo`: `date 11/11/2012`. It should change back to today's date with the final line, right? But it doesn't.

Comment: my code works well. I'm using Win 7 but that script works on all windows. If you've modified my code then update your question to see the error. anyway i've updated my answer again, try it (it works like the others...I don't know which error do you have)

Comment: The script won't work if `%date%` leads with day of the week, as it does on my machine: `Fri 11/23/2012`.

Comment: `%date%` or `%DATE:/=-%` still don't work. Regarding the error i have i already wrote it in the question but i will repeat it here again: `The system cannot accept the date entered.` But dbenham figured out the problem. So I will update the question with the find of dbenham.

Comment: Thanks Elektro for following this problem. Not sure why your system doesn't report an error, could it be that the first script line value doesn't include the day of the week on your system? I updated my question with the problem and 2 solutions, but not sure if they're applicable and how.